# Restore new iPhone from jailbreak backup

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

In iTunes I have backups of my current jailbroken iPhone (iOS 7).

Can I setup new iPhone (from store, iOS 8, not jailbroken) from this backup?
I don't care about Cydia and Cydia apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but a backup of a jailbroken device will restore all jailbreak data such as preference files and other data which will take up storage space on the device.